# Using Realm in iOS Today Extension

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an app with today extension. In `AppDelegate.swift` of MainApp:

```
let realmContext = try! Realm(fileURL: NSFileManager
        .defaultManager()
        .containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.this.is.test")!
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm"))
```

In my todayExtension's viewDidload:

```
let realmContext = try! Realm(fileURL: NSFileManager
        .defaultManager()
        .containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.this.is.test")!
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm"))
```

those are exactly same. But, it works in MainApp, and when I want to use it in today extension, I get `Unable to load` in Notification Center.
The problem is Realm, because when I remove `let realmContext = ...` from codes, today extension have no problem.
What is wrong?

Comment: Make sure that App Group is properly configured in your today extension. Can you also provide any error messages you see in Xcode console?

Answer (score 4):

It is probably due to running out memory. `Realm(fileURL:)` invoke objc_copyClassList() internally, it requires large amount of memory. It occasionally fails on app extensions because a memory is strictly limited (very very few) on app extension.

To avoid this, you can specify schemas explicitly using `objectTypes` setting in `Realm.Configuration`. When giving schemas explicitly, Realm doesn't invoke `objc_copyClassList()`, since no need to enumerate all classes.

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    fileURL: NSFileManager
        .defaultManager()
        .containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.this.is.test")!
        .URLByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm"),
    objectTypes: [SomeClass.self, AnotherClass.self])
let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
...
```